# CCTexture2D created texture.size not equal that image.size (only on iPad --> iPad simulator works fine)

Tags: ios, ipad, cocos2d-iphone

I have very weird problem. When I run this code

```
CCTexture2DMutable * texture = [[CCTexture2DMutable alloc] initWithCGImage:image.CGImage resolutionType: kCCResolutioniPadRetinaDisplay];

    CGFloat heightOfImage = image.size.height;
    CGFloat heightOfTexture = texture.contentSize.height;
```

**initWithCGImage** is mathod that was inherit from CCTexture2D.
image <-- UIImage

I get very weird result:

**On iPad simululator** (works fine):

heightOfImage = 1024

heightOfTexture = 1024

**On iPad (retina)** (not equal???):

heightOfImage = 1024

heightOfTexture = 512

Does any one know why? It drives me crazy.

If I change kCCResolutioniPadRetinaDisplay to kCCResolutioniPad the problem is the same.

Comment: Is your simulator set to Retina or non-Retina iPad? Is your iPad itself Retina?

Comment: My iPad is retina but if I change kCCResolutioniPadRetinaDisplay does the same

Comment: As I see the problem is retina becouse if i change simulator for retina the problem is the same.

Comment: I don't know how to solve this specific problem, but I have the feeling that it has to do with the image's `scale` property. Check the documentation for `CGImage` and `CCTexture2D` to make sure that you're handling the images' scale properties correctly.

Comment: Even if I resize the image x2 or even x4 it still return the small size. Looks like that have the reverse functionality. Instead of make it bigger if is retina it makes it smaller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cocos use points for measurement, not pixels (anymore). That's why the image size (in pixels) is different from the texture size (in points)